# Making Odata call for large number of data

Tags: c#, database, api, url, odata

I have the student list which contains the student IDs huge in size.
`List<int> student = {1, 2, 3,........}`
If we fetch the data using odatURL for each student using id will take some time
what i have decide is make the small parts of the list and for each list make the ODATA call like this
`{1,2} {3,4} {5, 6} etc` 
So suppose if we have 10 ids we will have 5 odata call to fetch the data. That will reduce the time.
So I want to make the one call for each small list that will fetch the details of the student based on student IDs and make the list.
expected result will be
`{1,2} => some odata URL => {{1, "A", "Mumbai"},{2, "B", "Delhi"}}`
So how should i make this odata URL......?
I am new to the odata

Comment: Check [filter option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_SystemQueryOptionfilter) of oData. I suppose you can use `in` operator, e.g. `/Students?$filter=Id in (1,2)`

Comment: How should I use variable name of list in filter.

Comment: `List<int> temp = {1, 2}` then `string odataExpression = $"$filter={studyID} in (temp)` that studyID will be anyone inside the temp regardless of this it will fetch all the data. Is this correct way to use..?